Hibernate 5: EntityGraph doesn't work with joins
I'm having trouble using an EntityGraph to override lazy loading on some attributes.
In the following examples Person.picture is annotated with @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY).
If I just load entities of a single type without any joins, it is working perfectly.
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> root = criteriaQuery.from(Person.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root);

TypedQuery<Person> typedQuery = this.entityManager.createQuery(query);
EntityGraph<Person> entityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Person.class);
entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("picture");
query.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", entityGraph);

List<Person> result = typedQuery.getResultList();

I see no proxies for Person.picture, but always the actual Picture object. I also can see in the generated SQL, that a JOIN is created for the table of Picture.
But when I do some joins, the EntityGraph is accepted and also validated, but not applied for some reasons:
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<DepartmentMember> root = criteriaQuery.from(DepartmentMember.class);
Join<DepartmentMember, Person> person = root.join("member", JoinType.INNER);
Join<DepartmentMember, Department> department = root.join("department", JoinType.INNER);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equals(department.get("name"), "development"));
criteriaQuery.select(person);

TypedQuery<Person> typedQuery = this.entityManager.createQuery(query);
EntityGraph<Person> entityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Person.class);
entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("picture");
query.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", entityGraph);

List<Person> result = typedQuery.getResultList();

I get Person entities always having a proxy set for Person.picture. In the generated SQL query I only see the JOINs I defined, but no additional ones. The EntityGraph is definitely validated, because if I add some non-existing attributes, the whole thing will throw an error.
I tried a different approach using fetch joins - which works. Like:
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<DepartmentMember> root = criteriaQuery.from(DepartmentMember.class);
Join<DepartmentMember, Person> person = root.join("member", JoinType.INNER);
person.fetch("picture");
Join<DepartmentMember, Department> department = root.join("department", JoinType.INNER);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equals(department.get("name"), "development"));
criteriaQuery.select(person);

TypedQuery<Person> typedQuery = this.entityManager.createQuery(query);

List<Person> result = typedQuery.getResultList();

Here I can see a JOIN in the generated SQL and Person.picture has no proxy, but the actual object.
Anyone aware what the reason could be why the EntityGraph is not working when joins are used? Anything wrong in my approach with EntityGraph?

A wild guess is to try starting the loadgraph from the root of the query, not the type. So, instead of Person->picture, something like DepartmentMember->member->picture. In code something like: var eg = em.createEntityGraph(DepartmentMember.class); var personSg = eg.addSubgraph("member"); personSg.addSubgraph("picture"); (will probably need tweaking to apply to your precise classes)

Thanks @NikosParaskevopoulos for your comment, much appreciated. Maybe I should have added it, but I also tried that. This will give me an exception that it can't find the attribute. I assume because it expects the entity graph to start actually at Person because that is the type returned by the query. I will try to set up a test project using the latest Hibernate 6 version. As mentioned in the title, I'm currently using the last Hibernate 5 version, but that is already 2 years old and maybe this is a bug which have been solved a long time ago on version 6. I'll report back.

Seems there is no way to get Hibernate 6 running with Spring Framework 2, as it uses the new jakarta.* namespace and Spring is on the old javax.* namespace. Means I also have to upgrade Spring.

After a lot back and forth - as Spring 5 + Hibernate 6.6 work differently than Spring 6 and Hibernate 6 - I finally was able to set up a small proof-of-concept application. And unfortunately I have to say that the EntityGraph works there as expected, no need for fetch-joins. I can see in the SQL statements created that it correctly inserts a LEFT JOIN and also that I don't get a proxy object for Person.picture. So I assume it is simply a bug in that latest Hibernate 5 version - which probably also will never get fixed. 
